# Python: Extracting values from a csv file and outputting into separate lists based on specific parameters

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a short script to process some csv data.
My data looks something like this:

```
Freq    res    loop
10000   10    1
100     11    1
10000   12    2
100     13    2
```

I need to extract all of the `res` values for each frequency and put them into a separate list. For example `10000 10 12` where 10000 is the frequency and 10 and 12 are the res values for loop 1 and 2.

A quick and dirty way to do this would be to cut the columns by loop count and stack them horizontally then read the data by row like this:

```
Freq    res    loop    Freq    res    loop
10000   10     1       10000   12     2
100     11     1       100     13     2
```

But I feel like that's brute forcing it and might get messy down the line.
I created a dictionary where `key[(Freq, loop)] = res` so that I can do something like:

```
for i in np.arange(1, max(loop)+1,1):
    print(key[10000,i])
```

But I am not sure how to also loop over the frequency and create a separate list for each.

I am still new to Python so any input would be appreciated. Also please let me know if I am missing a simpler solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pandas.read_csv(fname)
df.groupby('Freq')
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I've never really messed with pandas, but df.sort_values(by=['Frequency[Hz]','Loop']) worked.